# Importing Requests not Working Python 3.7

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

I'm running the latest Kali Linux with Python 3.7 and am trying to use the requests module. As you can see, I install requests but still cannot import it. Could someone help me reconcile this strange problem?

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# pip3 install --upgrade requests

Requirement already up-to-date: requests in 
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 
in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (1.23)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2018.10.15)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from requests) (2.7)

root@kali:~/Desktop# python3

Python 3.5.6 (default, Sep 29 2018, 21:41:04) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'requests'
```

Thanks ahead of time for the help!

Comment: You are running two different versions of Python (3.7 and 3.5.6), you need to install requests for 3.5.6, or set your environment correctly to use the 3.7 version of Python.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Add this as an answer and I'll accept and upvote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it appears you have multiple versions of `Python` installed you'll need to set your environment to use `Python 3.7` (currently it's set to 3.5.6, and requests doesn't appear to be installed).

In your `.bash_profile` you could probably do:

```
alias python3=/path/to/python3.7
```

which should use the 3.7 version when you enter `python3` ...